# Auto-zoom on orientation change in iOS 7

Tags: html, iphone, css, mobile, ios7

I had a web page that worked perfectly well until Apple came out with iOS 7 today and it broke the layout when screen orientation is changed.

Basically, when I have focus on a text area and rotate the screen to landscape view, the entire page zooms in. If focus is taken out of the text area and turned back to Portrait, things are back normal.

Rotation also works well when the text areas does not have focus.

I already have the following meta-tag in place (to ensure we block zooming):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0;;">
```

Any ideas what's causing this awkward behavior?

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean with "broken layout"?
I would like to see a screenshot!

The only thing I saw in my websites, is that the form elements are getting out of the view, as the content lenght is changeing. Im talking about a responsive desing ofc.
Maybe there is a JS to fix this...

Im not preventing the zoom of a website, unless it is a tool that simulates an app
or the customer wants it so. ;)

But im preventing the standard zoom when focusing form elements with jQuery, or JS if jQuery is not in use!

```
$("input[type=text], textarea, select").focus(function(){
        $('head meta[name=viewport]').remove();
        $('head').prepend('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />');
     }).blur(function(){
        $('head meta[name=viewport]').remove();
        $('head').prepend('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1;" />');
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned, it basically just zooms in the page to around 300% of the original size, which leads to users having to scroll through the page